# Jhipster EHCache doesn't evict id from duplicated entity

Tags: hibernate, jhipster, ehcache, jhipster-registry

I'm actually developing  a jhipster application. It's an awsome code generator but it didn't allow me to make relationships to default User entity. So i foundout the table name of that entity and I made another entity MyUser linked to the same table on bbdd.
It seems to work fine and generated me the jpa relationships correctly, but instead ine class i had 2 different classes.
But after a time I have realised if i change one of that entities, the other one doesn't change.If I quit the cache from one of that entities it seems to work.
How can I prevent this from happening without disabling that entity's cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Hibernate doesn't like two entities on the same table. Please don't do that.

Actually, referencing the existing User class works perfectly. I do it all the time.

Just generate your new entity and add a relationship. Then specify "user" as the other entity name and that's it. If you look at the final `.json` file created in the `.jhipster` directory, it should look like this (the `otherEntityField` is the field you want to see on the generated CRUD GUI):

```
"relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipName": "user",
        "otherEntityName": "user",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "otherEntityField": "login"
    }
]
```